# lag date upon condition, carry over

Tags: r, time-series

I have repeated measurements over individuals who have made donations, or not, when solicited. I wish I could carry over the last successful solicitation date to the next observations until a new success is hit.

Here is my sample data:

```
set.seed(13)
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(letters[1:3], each=4), 
             SolicitationDate= sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), 
as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"), 3),
             Success=rbinom(4,1,0.2))

df$ExpectedResult <- c(NA, NA, "2016-06-28", "2016-06-28",
                NA, NA, "2016-10-11", "2016-10-11",
                NA,NA,"2017-06-03", "2017-06-03")
```

Should an individual have multiple successes, the last success date should be carrried over.

Thanks
Romain

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using `tidyverse`. I think your expected output may be off as the dates should be ordered within ID but that may be wrong. In that case let me know.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%    # Group by ID
  arrange(SolicitationDate) %>%     # Sort according to date
  mutate(res=replace(SolicitationDate, Success==0, NA)) %>%   # Create new value
  tidyr::fill(res)    # Fill down
```

This will give you

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID    SolicitationDate Success res       
   <fct> <date>             <int> <date>    
 1 a     2016-06-28             1 2016-06-28
 2 a     2016-10-11             0 2016-06-28
 3 a     2017-06-03             0 2016-06-28
 4 a     2017-06-03             0 2016-06-28
 5 b     2016-06-28             0 NA        
 6 b     2016-06-28             0 NA        
 7 b     2016-10-11             1 2016-10-11
 8 b     2017-06-03             0 2016-10-11
 9 c     2016-06-28             0 NA        
10 c     2016-10-11             0 NA        
11 c     2016-10-11             0 NA        
12 c     2017-06-03             1 2017-06-03
```

I'm not sure if you want the success dates to be part of the result or not. If not then you could set to missing and fill down again. In any case: hope this helps.